# In Scala, how would you declare static data inside a function?

Tags: scala

In many situations I find that I need to create long-living values inside a function's scope, and there is no need for this data to be at class/object scope.

For example,

```
object Example {

   def activeUsers = {
       val users = getUsersFromDB  // Connects to the database and runs a query.
       users.filter(_.active)
   }
}
```

Above, the variable `users` is in the correct scope, but it will execute a database query everytime the function `activeUsers` is called.

To avoid this, I could move the variable `users` outside the function's scope:

```
object Example {
   val users = getUsersFromDB  // Connects to the database and runs a query

   def activeUsers = {
       users.filter(_.active)
   }
}
```

But that makes it available to other functions as well.

Else, I could create a separate object to enclose the function:

```
object Example {

   object activeUsers {
       val users = getUsersFromDB  // Connects to the database and runs a query.

       def apply() = {
           users.filter(_.active)
       }
   }
}
```

But this involves more boilerplate code, use of another object and slight syntax oddities related to `apply`.

- Is there support for something like this at the language level?
- If not, is there any standard technique that you use in this situation?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Another option would be using a closure:

```
object Example {
   val activeUsers = {
       val users = getUsersFromDB
       () => users.filter(_.active)
   }
}
```

### Explanation

`activeUsers` is a variable of type `Function1[Unit, ...your filter result type...]` (or we can write this type as `(Unit => ...your filter result type...)`, which is the same), that is this variable stores a function. Thus you may use it later in a way indistinguishable from function, like `activeUsers()`

We initialize this variable with a block of code where we declare variable `users` and use it inside an anonymous function `() => users.filter(_.active)`, hence it is a closure (as it has a bound variable `users`).

As a result, we achieve your goals: (1) `activeUsers` looks like a method; (2) `users` is calculated once; and (3) `filter` works on every call.

Comment: Spot on. You might want to explain what is happening in there, and why does it work.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am still hoping to find a more sugary syntax akin to C's "static" variables.

Answer (score 6):

Extending FunctionXX is another way of achieving the goal; it might have an advantage of providing better documentation.  Both parameter types and return value type are visible on the first line of the declaration:

```
val activeUser = new Function0[List[String]] {
  val users = getUsersFromDB
  def apply = users filter (_.active)
}
```