# Can I define “method-private” fields in Scala?

Tags: scala, initialization, private, access-modifiers

Given this situation:

```
object ResourceManager {

  private var inited = false

  def init(config: Config) {
    if (inited)
      throw new IllegalStateException
    // do initialization
    inited = true
  }

}
```

Is there any way that I could make `inited` somehow “private to init()”, such that I can be sure that no other method in this class will ever be able to set `inited = false`?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516087

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taken from [In Scala, how would you declare static data inside a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516087/in-scala-how-would-you-declare-static-data-inside-a-function/1516196#1516196). Don’t use a method but a function object:

```
val init = { // or lazy val
  var inited = false

  (config: Config) => {
      if (inited)
          throw new IllegalStateException

      inited = true
  }
}
```

During initialisation of the outer scope (in case of `val`) or first access (`lazy val`), the body of the variable is executed. Thus, `inited` is set to `false`. The last expression is an anonymous function which is then assigned to `init`. Every further access to `init` will then execute this anonymous function.

Note that it does not behave *exactly* like a method. I.e. it is perfectly valid to call it without arguments. It will then behave like a method with trailing underscore `method _`, which means that it will just return the anonymous function without complaining.

If for some reason or another, you actually need method behaviour, you could make it a `private val _init = ...` and call it from public `def init(config: Config) = _init(config)`.

Comment: Good answer. I was thinking about this, but I wasn't making the jump from `def` to `val` to make it work.

Comment: Pretty, if almost too clever.

Comment: As a follow-up that includes set-once variables assigned only in the init code, see this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404024/how-to-simulate-an-assign-once-var-in-scala/4407534#4407534

Answer (score 5):

The below absolutely counts as way more trouble that it's worth, but does satisfy the specs.  There's no way to do so otherwise

```
object ResourceManager {

  private object foo {
     var inited = false
     def doInit(config:Config){
       if (inited)
         throw new IllegalStateException
       // do initialization
       inited = true
     }
  }


  def inner(config: Config) {
      foo.doInit(config)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is make sure that `init` is called once, do something like this:

```
lazy val inited = {
  // do the initialization
  true
}

def init = inited
```

that way the initialization code will only run once, however many times you run `init`, and `inited` cannot get another value since it's a `val`. The only downside is that as soon as  `inited` is queried for its value the initialization will run...

Comment: The problem here is that he doensn't wan't inited to be set, but it's value could be checked before the properly inicialization.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to create a "trapdoor" object which can only go from false to true:

```
object ResourceManager {

  object inited {
    private var done = false

    def apply() = done
    def set = done = true
  }

  def init(config: Int) {

    if (inited())
      throw new IllegalStateException
    // do initialization
    inited.set
  }

}
```

Comment: But couldn't inited.set be called by another method?

Comment: You said "be sure no other method can set `inited = false`".  There's no way for *any* method to set it to false with `set` in my example.